# MatLab - understanding input of plot3

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a brief question regarding the `plot3` function in MatLab.

Say I write the following:

```
x = [1 1 -1 1];
y = [4 4 4 4];
z = [-1 1 1 -1];

plot3(x,y,z)
```

Why does MatLab then draw a triangle with vertices in (-1,4-1), (1, 4, -1) and (1,4,1) instead of just plotting the points (-1, 4, -1), (1, 4, -1) and (1, 4, 1)?

Comment: I think what you want is scatter3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default line style for `plot` and `plot3` is a line, not just points.  If you want to plot just the points, use a different style:

```
plot3(x,y,z,'or'); #% plots red circles at each point
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot :).  Appreciate it.